# Ionic doesn't run on Android because of transition error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

My ionic app runs well in the browser and runs well on my Android phone when I connect it via USB and I am debugging.

But when I build a fresh .apk file and install that one (via e-mail) on my phone, nothing happens. To see what is going on I installed and enabled VorlonJs.

Thanks to Vorlon I can see what is going on. In the console log of Vorlon (which reads the console log of my android phone) I can see this message

```
t r a n s i t i o n  f a i l e d
t r a n s i t i o n  a b o r t e d
t r a n s i t i o n  p r e v e n t e d
t r a n s i t i o n  s u p e r s e d e d
```

How can I solve this and maybe someone know how to disable the transition so at least my app is working?

EDIT

I have created a blank project with this routing:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'account/login.html',
        controller: 'AccountController',
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: '/account/register.html',
        controller: 'AccountController',
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

And this also gives the same problem. When I run this newly blank app I can't go from 'login' to 'register'. In chrome and in debug mode (`ionic run android --device -c -l`) everything works fine.

For the completeness here is all of my code:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core']);

app
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    Ionic.io();

    var push = new Ionic.Push({});

    push.register(function(token) {
      // Log out your device token (Save this!)
      console.log("Got Token:",token.token);
    });
  });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    /*.state('account', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/account',
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
    })*/
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'account/login.html',
        controller: 'AccountController',
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: '/account/register.html',
        controller: 'AccountController',
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://recipeapi.demaffia.nl:1337/vorlon.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/UrlService.js"></script>
    <script src="account/AccountService.js"></script>
    <script src="account/AccountController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/storage/localstorage.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>

      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>

      </ion-content>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>

  </body>
</html>
```

account/login.html

```
<ion-view title="Inloggen">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <form name="form.login" data-ng-submit="vm.login()">

            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <span class="input-label">Emailadres</span>
                    <input type="text" class="full-width" placeholder="Emailadres" data-ng-model="login.Email" required="required">
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <span class="input-label">Wachtwoord</span>
                    <input type="password" class="full-width" placeholder="Wachtwoord" data-ng-model="login.Password" required="required">
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <input type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" value="Login" ng-disabled="!form.login.$valid" />
            <a ui-sref="register" class="button button-block button-balanced">Registreren</a>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

account/register.html

```
<ion-view title="Registreren">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <form name="form.register" data-ng-submit="vm.register()">

            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <span class="input-label">Naam</span>
                    <input type="text" class="full-width" placeholder="Naam" data-ng-model="login.Name" required="required">
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <span class="input-label">Emailadres</span>
                    <input type="text" class="full-width" placeholder="Emailadres" data-ng-model="login.Email" required="required">
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <span class="input-label">Wachtwoord</span>
                    <input type="password" class="full-width" placeholder="Wachtwoord" data-ng-model="login.Password" required="required">
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <input type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" value="Registreer" ng-disabled="!form.register.$valid" />
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: That is always difficult to debug. You can try installing the app via `ionic run --device` and install the same built APK via `adb install` and via email.

Comment: @KateMihalikova Thanks for the suggestions, but it still doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the routing. I have created a new blank project with only 2 states in it and I can't transition from state 1 to state 2. See my updated post.

Comment: Make a debug apk and put a link here.

Comment: @KateMihalikova Here is a link to a rar file with the 'android-debug.apk' and 'android-debug-unaligned': http://recipe.demaffia.nl/apk.rar This is just my simple app asdescribed above, with two pages.

Comment: @KateMihalikova Did you have to time to look at it? Thanks for helping me out, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sorry, no problem at my device, aside of `No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.` error. Please use Chrome Remote DevTools (`chrome://inspect/`) to inspect your app's console while the phone is connected to your PC.

Comment: @KateMihalikova You're my hero of this month. Thanks to your suggestion to use `chrome://inspect/` I could see that the error message was `cannot find file`. In my routing I prefixed all template urls with a `/`. After removing all these slashes it works on my phone as a standalone app! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments debugging summary:

- There was some kind of error in javascript, which prevents the app from even starting.
- Debugging using remote console.log (VorlonJS) was not succesful.
- Suggested debugging via [Chrome Remote DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) revealed that app files were not found due to included `/` in front of all relative URIs.

  - Apps exported to APK are using complex URIs which includes subdirectories that are ignored when using leading slashes so they cannot be included.
- After removing those slashes the app is working fine.

Comment: Thanks again, but could you elaborate some more on the URI part? Why are subdirectories ignored? Are all the files and subfolders stored in one place? So all the files and dorectories are placed directy in the root?

Comment: With `ionic serve` yes, everything is stored in root, so your app was working with leading slashes. On the device the files are stored in some subdirectories and thus they were not found with leading slashes.

Comment: Thank you, so a good advice will be to refer files always to it's relative path, otherwise you are referring to the root of the device

Comment: Always use relative, don't bother with the exact place where root uri leads, that is platform and implementation specific.